# WPF Animation - Rotate elements on button click

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to rotate two elements from 0 to angles: 1. Element (ClampL) 45 angle and 2. Element (ClampR) -45 Angle, but they should move together. The elements are 2 clamps which are open and when they grab something, they close and this process should happen on button click.

**Here is my XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF_AnimatedLift.View.Prozess"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_AnimatedLift.View" xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:WPF_AnimatedLift.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="1000">
    



    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Margin="0,0,-163,-83">

        

        <Path x:Name="ClampR" Fill="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="2.12787" Data="M 524.2207 473.57227 L 524.2207 563.57227 L 137.14258 563.57227 L 137.14258 652.14258 L 571.42773 652.14258 L 571.42773 563.57227 L 571.36328 563.57227 L 571.36328 473.57227 L 524.2207 473.57227 z " Height="68.668" Stretch="Fill" Width="80.734" Canvas.Left="411.375" Canvas.Top="339.125" >
            <Path.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ClampR"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                From="0"
                                To="360"
                                Duration="0:0:5"
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Path.Triggers>
            <Path.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.265" ScaleX="0.265"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="-45"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Path.LayoutTransform>
        </Path>

        <Path x:Name="ClampL" Fill="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="2.12787" Data="M 110 344.28516 L 110 434.28516 L 110 485.71484 L 110 522.85742 L 544.28516 522.85742 L 544.28516 434.28516 L 157.14258 434.28516 L 157.14258 344.28516 L 110 344.28516 z " Height="68.668" Stretch="Fill" Width="80.734" Canvas.Left="384.508" Canvas.Top="339.166">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.265" ScaleX="0.265"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>


        <Button Content="START" Canvas.Left="84" Canvas.Top="403" Width="106" Height="48" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Name="BtnStart" Command="{Binding ClickCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click"> //???
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>

    </Canvas>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:ProzessViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
</UserControl>
```

As you can see in code, I tried with Path.Trigger, DoubleAnimation, but it doesn't work, can someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, in EventTrigger, you can only refer the elements that exist inside that FrameworkElement. The solution would be different depending on where you want to set EventTrigger.

**1. Button**

You can use EventTrigger in the Button, which is the source of `Button.Click` event, like the following. The elements are simplified to a minimum for brevity and the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` is modified to circumvent TransformGroup.

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Path x:Name="ClampR"
          Canvas.Left="411" Canvas.Top="339"
          Width="80" Height="68"
          Fill="Black"
          Data="M 0,0 1,0 0,1 z" Stretch="Fill">
        <Path.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.265" ScaleX="0.265"/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="-45"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.LayoutTransform>
    </Path>

    <Button x:Name="BtnStart"
            Canvas.Left="84" Canvas.Top="403"
            Width="106" Height="48"
            Content="START">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ClampR"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.Children[2].Angle"
                            From="0" To="360"
                            Duration="0:0:5"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Canvas>
```

**2. Canvas**

As `Button.Click` is RoutedEvent and propagated to the root, you can use EventTrigger at parent level. In this case, at Canvas.Triggers.

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Canvas.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ClampR"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.Children[2].Angle"
                        From="0" To="360"
                        Duration="0:0:5"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Canvas.Triggers>

    <Path x:Name="ClampR"
          Canvas.Left="411" Canvas.Top="339"
          Width="80" Height="68"
          Fill="Black"
          Data="M 0,0 1,0 0,1 z" Stretch="Fill">
        <Path.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.265" ScaleX="0.265"/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="-45"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.LayoutTransform>
    </Path>

    <Button x:Name="BtnStart"
            Canvas.Left="84" Canvas.Top="403"
            Width="106" Height="48"
            Content="START"/>
</Canvas>
```

**3. Path**

Unlike standard EventTrigger, EventTrigger of  [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) is more robust and can refer other controls. Thus it can work in the Path.

```xml
Add xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors" in header.

<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Path x:Name="ClampR"
          Canvas.Left="411" Canvas.Top="339"
          Width="80" Height="68"
          Fill="Black"
          Data="M 0,0 1,0 0,1 z" Stretch="Fill">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger SourceName="BtnStart" EventName="Click">
                <i:ControlStoryboardAction>
                    <i:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Rotation"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                From="0" To="360"
                                Duration="0:0:5"
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </i:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                </i:ControlStoryboardAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Path.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.265" ScaleX="0.265"/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="Rotation" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="-45"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.LayoutTransform>
    </Path>

    <Button x:Name="BtnStart"
            Canvas.Left="84" Canvas.Top="403"
            Width="106" Height="48"
            Content="START"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I would give you vote, but I don't have enough rep. :)